# Sql get without duplicates based on a field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 3 fields

```
PId Name Address 
1    aaaa   1234
2    bbbb   4567
3    cccc   1234
4    dddd   4567
```

My query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.Name,ss.Name From Students s INNER JOIN Students ss ON s.PId!=ss.PId WHERE s.Address = ss.Address GROUP BY s.Name,ss.Name
```

I want to get the name who have same address , but iam getting like this

```
aaaa cccc
bbbb dddd
cccc aaaa
dddd bbbb
```

And i want

```
aaaa cccc
bbbb dddd
```

only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
SELECT
    s.Name,
    ss.Name
FROM
    Students s
INNER JOIN
    Students ss ON s.PId != ss.PId
WHERE
    s.Address = ss.Address
AND
    s.Name < ss.Name
GROUP BY
    s.Name,
    ss.Name
```

?

If the names are unique to the rows, you can also write:

```
SELECT
    s.Name,
    ss.Name
FROM
    Students s
INNER JOIN
    Students ss ON s.PId != ss.PId
WHERE
    s.Address = ss.Address
AND
    s.Name < ss.Name
```

Answer (score 2):

shorter

```
   SELECT
   s.Name,
  ss.Name
FROM
    Students s
INNER JOIN
    Students ss ON  s.Address = ss.Address 
    and s.PId != ss.PId 
where s.name<ss.name
```

or

```
SELECT
   s.Name  ,
  ss.Name
FROM
    Students s
INNER JOIN
    Students ss ON  s.Address = ss.Address 
    and s.PId != ss.PId 
    and s.name<ss.name
```

the group by is Unnecessary